# How to set a date for WKInterfaceDate

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

Can WKInterfaceDate show a date & time different from the current values?

If yes, how can I set a different date?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

apple documentation says:

> A WKInterfaceDate object is a custom label that displays the **current**
>   date or time. Use this object when you want to display date or time
>   information **without further interaction** from your WatchKit extension.
>   At runtime, use the date object to configure the appearance of the
>   date and time information being displayed.

For different date you can simply create label and set it's text to a String that you create with NSDateFormatter out of some NSDate.